# How to unpair Nokia Treasure Tag

Tags: lumia, treasure-tag

I have a Nokia Treasure Tag paired with my Nokia Lumia 920 phone but I want to pair it with my new Nokia Lumia 930 phone but it can not be paired. How can I reset the Nokia Treasure Tag so I can pair it with the new phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: In the Treasure Tag app, select your tag, then expand the app bar and tap "remove tag". You should now be able to pair the tag with another phone.

Option 2: If the above doesn't work, you can restore the tag to its factory settings by removing the battery and then reinserting it while pressing the button on the front of the tag.
If you have the Mini model that doesn't have the button, simply reinsert the battery.

For more information on using your Treasure Tag, including how to remove the battery, see the user guide, available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/product/ws-2) for the WS-2 Treasure Tag and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/product/ws-10) for the WS-10 Treasure Tag Mini.

Comment: had one of these for ages wondering why it wouldn't work with my new phone. didn't realise it was still paired to my old phone. The 2nd option worked straight away :)